# How to combine for loops with 2+ variables?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have multiple for loops that pull dates from one data frame and match them to specific rows/columns in another data frame. I'm looking for help turning this into a single function or loop.

I've tried nested for loops without any luck.

The loops I have look like this and do what I need them to do:

```
for(x in id_vector) {
  datafileslist[[x]]$m3start <- rep(dates_df[[x,3]], nrow(datafileslist[[x]]))
}

for(x in id_vector) {
  datafileslist[[x]]$m3end <- rep(dates_df[[x,4]], nrow(datafileslist[[x]]))
}

for(x in id_vector) {
  datafileslist[[x]]$m6start <- rep(dates_df[[x,5]], nrow(datafileslist[[x]]))
}
```

...and so on. While this works, there is a lot of repetition (I have 16 for loops).

I've tried this instead:

```
for(x in seq_along(id_vector)) {
  for(z in 3:18) {
    for(y in 20:35) {
  datafileslist[[x]][[y]] <- rep(dates_df[[x,z]], nrow(datafileslist[[x]]))
    }
  }
}
```

But I need matched pairs of z and y to run once in tandem (3, 20; 4, 21; ... 18, 35) through each id, which the above code does not do. Any ideas on how I can do this?

The dates_df looks like this:

```
id          m3start           m3end
s01         2016-09-19        2016-12-17
s02         2016-11-03        2017-01-31
```

There are 60 ids and 16 combos of start/end dates (m3, m6, m9, etc.).

The data files list is a list of data frames, one data frame per id, with 50,000+ observations of around 20 variables for each id. I'm trying to add columns with start and end dates for each date range from the dates_df data frame to the data frame for each id.

The output should look like something like this:

```
id          group          m3start          m3end          m6start
s01         int            2016-09-19       2016-12-17     2018-09-08
s01         int            2016-09-19       2016-12-17     2018-09-08
s01         int            2016-09-19       2016-12-17     2018-09-08
```

When I run the nested for loops, I get the same dates across m3start, m3end, m6start, m6end, etc.

```
id          group          m3start          m3end          m6start
s01         int            2020-01-12       2020-01-12     2020-01-12
s01         int            2020-01-12       2020-01-12     2020-01-12
s01         int            2020-01-12       2020-01-12     2020-01-12
```

Comment: provide some sample input data and expected output. Its unclear what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Have a look at `mapply` to run through two lists in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `merge` inside an `lapply` on list of data frames:

```
new_datafileslist <- lapply(datafileslist, function(df) merge(df, dates_df, by="id"))
```